# Unable to browse SMB shares on Azure VM

Tags: azure

I've setup an Azure VM to do some proof of concept testing for our application. I'm able to RDP into the server, as well as access the SQL instance setup in it via Management Studio from my machine. (Don't worry, its IP restricted to my public IP!) I've setup the appropriate endpoints, but I'm not able to get SMB working.

I have a file share setup that is used for merge replication, and the client needs to access that to get the snapshot file to begin replication. I am able to telnet to the RDP port, the SQL port, but not 445. I've opened both TCP and UDP 445 endpoints in Azure, and for good measure, disabled the firewall on the server itself.

Running a `netstat -an` on the server shows 0.0.0.0:445 listening. Am I missing something here that is central to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `Wireshark` to see whats going on at network layer as your ISP may be blocking this, if you can try to access it from another network.

Comment: You may need to re-read my question. I have already setup endpoints for 445 and Windows firewall is off for the time being.

Comment: Many ISPs block SMB in their routers by default to protect their users. So, you should run Wireshark on both ends and see what happens when you try to mount an SMD share. I guess you will see no packets coming into the server.